# Read AT COMMAND output using c code?

Tags: c, gsm, at-command, serial-communication

I want to read output of my AT command which is sent to GSM modem using c code.I made a code but in this code buffer is not showing proper output.please help me.
I want to print the cell information using this code.AT command which is I use is "AT+CCED=0,2".

```
int main()
{
  int fd;  // File descriptor
  int n,i;
  char buf[1000]={"\0"}; 
  char com[20]={"at+cced=0,2\r"};       
  fd = open_port();

  // Read the configureation of the port

  struct termios options;
  tcgetattr( fd, &options );

  /* SEt Baud Rate */

  cfsetispeed( &options, B115200 );
  cfsetospeed( &options, B115200 );

  //I don't know what this is exactly

  options.c_cflag |= ( CLOCAL | CREAD );

  // Set the Charactor size

  options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; /* Mask the character size bits */
  options.c_cflag |= CS8;    /* Select 8 data bits */

  // Set parity - No Parity (8N1)

  options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
  options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
  options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
  options.c_cflag |= CS8;

  options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);

  // Disable Software Flow control

  options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);

  // Chose raw (not processed) output

  options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

  if ( tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW, &options ) == -1 )
    printf ("1Error with tcsetattr = %s\n", strerror ( errno ) );
  else
    printf ( "%s\n", "tcsetattr succeed" );

  fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);


  // Write some stuff !!!

  n = write(fd, com, strlen(com));
  if (n < 0)
    fputs("write() of 4 bytes failed!\n", stderr);
  else
    printf ("Write succeed n  = %i\n", n );

  n=0;
  i=0;
  while (1) 
  {
    n = read( fd, buf, sizeof(buf) );

    if(n>0)
    {   
      printf("%s", buf);    
      fflush(stdout);
    }
    //   i=i+1;
  }

  close( fd );
  return 0;
}           

int open_port(void)
{
  int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */

  fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
  if (fd == -1)
  {
    perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyUSB0 - ");
  }
  else
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);

  printf ( "In Open port fd = %i\n", fd); 
  return (fd);
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question, such that you only provide a minimum of code (likely no one will read through the code you supplied). Have a look at [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I've done a project like this before but I used Java! It was very similar (and painful).

I will give you a walk through of what I did to make it work:

1. Did you set the correct rates and bit flags of the serial port?
2. Use `Putty` or `Super Terminal` to ensure that you can communicate with your GSM modem *BEFORE* trying to code anything.
3. Ensure you give some idle time to wait for the GSM modem to start (aka: warming up time).
4. Some special `chars` cause problems - are you handling them correctly?
5. Are you sending `EOF`, `\r\n`, or `\0` (depends on the GSM modem) at the end of your communication? -> Sometimes you won't get any messages until you send this special char.

Also make use of tested libraries:

- [Serial Library C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/992/Serial-library-for-C)
- [RS-232 for Win and Linux](http://sigrok.org/wiki/Libserialport)
- **[Lib Serial Port](http://sigrok.org/wiki/Libserialport)** <- recommended

> Alternatively you can use online GSM/SMS services if your whole project depends on the service rather than the modem itself.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I don't know the java much so I want to do it in C.

Comment: @yogeshbhimani did you read my answer properly? I gave you `C` code examples and libraries.

Comment: The libserialport library looks really nice, I plan to start using it.